# how to get current page after refreshing webpage in asp.net?

Tags: ajax

I have 40 records in a database, but I am displaying 10 records in each page in store grid by using grid panel.

Similarly, I am using Ajax for events. The problem is when I refresh the page or grid, it shows the first record in the first page. How can I get current page data when refreshing data?

How can I avoid this problem, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a session in your back-end that remembers the current index (updated when you do your ajax requests) and when you reload the page start from that index.

Comment: I have done it. But it is not binding to particular page. This is the code:  protected void Refresh_Click(object sender, StoreRefreshDataEventArgs e)
        {
            Refresh();            
            pgtCombo.PageIndex = (int)Session["pgIndex"];            
            pgtCombo.PageSize = (int)Session["pgSize"];          
            Session["pgIndex"] = string.Empty;
            Session["pgSize"] = string.Empty;
        }

Comment: What language are you using on the server side? You should also probably re-tag your question to include that as well, as the problem you are now trying to solve are connected with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you reload the page (e.g. with the `F5` key), the server receives a brand new request and the context of the previous request is lost, so the grid view renders its first page again.

However, if you only post back to the server (e.g. by clicking a button that submits the page), and [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate.aspx) is enabled for the grid view, it should retain its current page.

If you absolutely want to preserve the current page across page reloads (and not only postbacks), you need to persist the current page index somewhere, e.g. in the user's [session state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx):

```
Session["CurrentGridViewPage"] = yourGridView.PageIndex;
```

And restore that on page load:

```
if (Session["CurrentGridViewPage"] != null) {
    yourGridView.PageIndex = (int) Session["CurrentGridViewPage"];
}
```

**EDIT:** If you need to persist the page index for several pages on your website, you need to include in the session key some token uniquely identifying the page, e.g. [Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.apprelativecurrentexecutionfilepath.aspx):

```
protected string PageIndexSessionKey
{
    get {
        return Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath + "$pgIndex";
    }
}

// Save.
Session[PageIndexSessionKey] = yourGridView.PageIndex;

// Restore.
if (Session[PageIndexSessionKey] != null) {
    yourGridView.PageIndex = (int) Session[PageIndexSessionKey];
}
```

Comment: I have done it. But it is not binding to particular page. This is the code:  protected void Refresh_Click(object sender, StoreRefreshDataEventArgs e)
        {
            Refresh();            
            pgtCombo.PageIndex = (int)Session["pgIndex"];            
            pgtCombo.PageSize = (int)Session["pgSize"];          
            Session["pgIndex"] = string.Empty;
            Session["pgSize"] = string.Empty;
        }

Comment: @user490030, you're right. That's fixed in my updated answer.